# Why is this named 3-phenyl-2-butanol instead of 2-phenyl-3-butanol?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

Why is the following compound named 3-phenyl-2-butanol and not 2-phenyl-3-butanol? Does the alcohol or the phenyl group have priority?

[image: 3-phenylbutan-2-ol]

Answer (score 4):

You have already correctly identified the compound as a **phenylbutanol.** The only remaining problem is the numbering of locants. The most important simplified criteria for the numbering in such cases are:

1. lower locants for the principal characteristic group that is expressed as suffix
2. lower locants for multiple bonds (first to double bonds if there is a choice)
3. lower locants for prefixes
4. lower locants for substituents cited first as a prefix in the name

The corresponding actual wording in the current version of *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069)* reads as follows:

> **P-14.4** NUMBERING
>
> When several structural features appear in cyclic and acyclic compounds, low locants are assigned to them in the following decreasing order of seniority:
>
> (…)
>
> (c) principal characteristic groups and free valences (suffixes);
>
> (…)
>
> (e) saturation/unsaturation:
>
> (i) low locants are given to hydro/dehydro prefixes (…) and ‘ene’ and ‘yne’ endings;
>
> (ii) low locants are given first to multiple bonds as a set and then to double bonds (…);
>
> (f) detachable alphabetized prefixes, all considered together in a series of increasing numerical order;
>
> (g) lowest locants for the substituent cited first as a prefix in the name;
>
> (…)

Clearly, the $\ce{-OH}$ group is the principal characteristic group in this case since you have already used it as principal characteristic group to find the correct suffix ‘ol’.

Therefore, a low locant is assigned first to the $\ce{-OH}$ group according to Rule (c), which yields phenylbutan-2-ol.

After that, a low locant is assigned to the phenyl group according to Rule (f); however, the only possible numbering left is **3-phenylbutan-2-ol.**

[image: 3-phenylbutan-2-ol]